# Why do I get the error "Member 'object.Equals(object, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"?

Tags: c#

Consider this program,

```
using System;
namespace My.Namespace
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static bool EqualsIgnoreCase(this string s1, string s2)
        {
            return s1.Equals(s2, true);
        }
        public static bool Equals(this string s1, string s2,
                                  bool ignoreCase)
        {
            StringComparison sc = ignoreCase ?
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase :
                StringComparison.Ordinal;
            return string.Compare(s1, s2, sc) == 0;
        }
    }
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string s1 = "abc";
            string s2 = "ABC";
            bool result = s1.Equals(s2, true);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

which should compile fine, but using .NET 4.8.1, I get a compiler error on this line of code,

```
s1.Equals(s2, true);
```

The error message is,

```
Member 'object.Equals(object, object)' cannot be accessed with
an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.
```

The use of the extension looks correct.

I was expecting the code to compile, but I get an error that I don't understand.

The answer cited as the reason for closing my question uses params, and creates an ambiguous signature.  My extension method does not use params and is an extension method that has no pre-existing signature, so to me the prior answers don't seem to address the dilemma I've found.

Also, subsequent comments said the program works fine, but I'm specifically asking about .NET 4.8.1 (where it absolutely ***does*** fail), not the latest .NET Core offering.

So, that's another question: why does this code fail to compile on .NET 4.8.1 but compiles fine on the latest .NET Core?

Comment: Have you imported the extension method with a `using` statement?

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IW9nyP) with the code you've provided. Please [edit] your post with a [mre].

Comment: I added the reproducible example.

Comment: @KickingTheTires [It works just fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AZz87t), assuming you use the correct namespace. [If you don't](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BmHGJc) it won't work. So check that you are using/referencing the correct namespace and add a MCVE if necessary.

Comment: Ok, but when I use that website and your example program and select .NET 4.7.2 it does not work, I get the same compiler error as what I'm reporting here.

Comment: I can confirm that https://dotnetfiddle.net/EEuMsJ does not compile under .NET 4.7.2, but does compile (and works as expected) on any version since .NET Core 3.1. Voting to reopen.

Comment: It's been 4 days, is my question not worthy of an answer?  Why has it not been re-opened?